# disable telemetry in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want disable telemetry in Visual Studio 2015.
I found this document 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_how-to-disable-telemetry-reporting

But i VS2015 i dont understand where i can  find setting  ($username$ /document/ visual studio 2015/ ?) file  and  how put the string in right way
   "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false
   "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false
 thanks

Comment: The document you are referring to is for "Visual Studio Code" - a different product.